# Compare values in two arrays using Iterator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know how to compare values in two arrays using 2 for loops however I was looking for something a bit more sophisticated like creating an iterator to iterate through one of the arrays and passing the other array to `map`method . Is that even possible?

I'm doing a small program for class which takes an array and x `arguments` and I currently have extracted the values from the arguments.

```
function dest(arr){
  var args =[];
  for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  return args;
}

console.log(dest([1, 2, 3, 4], 4, 4));
```

Now, how could I do the iterator part to compare the values inside `arr` and `args`? Thanks for the help.

The result should be the results that match from both `arr` and `args`.

Comment: Do you realize arrays start at index zero?

Comment: please supply a wanted result.

Comment: @epascarello I just want to get the arguments from index 1 avoiding the arr.

Comment: @epascarello I think he does and the array passed as first argument is being skipped on purpose.

Comment: So what is your goal? You want to loop what and do what?

Comment: I think I was not clear enough, I want to compare `arr` to the newly created `args` which are both array after I extract args from the function. And the question states clearly that I want to use an iterator and not a for loop.

Comment: and what should the result be?

Comment: The result should be the results that match from both arr and args.

Comment: please ... match is not an answer. how match the same value at the same position, the value somewhere in the array, and why 4 two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in filter method

```
var arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var args = [3, 5, 6, 7];

var result = arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) > -1;
});
```

This will filter out all the elements out that are not present in both arrays. The result is a new array that contains only the matching values [3, 5, 6].